# Power BI - Data not refreshing on web published report predictably

Tags: powerbi

**UPDATE:**

It turns put this seems to refresh after an hour or so if you refresh the url.  I can't find any documentation on this time frame.

Any pointers to docs on this or if I can change it to be faster would be appreciated.

---

My requirement is that I need to display a report on a wall mounted screen (without logging  in as I use a special service to display it) and have it refresh the data regularly.

I have a scheduled dataset refresh that works fine from MySQL.

Dashboards refresh automatically but I can't use a dashboard as these can't be web published (need to log in).

I have published a report to the web but even when the dataset is refreshed in PBI Service and I navigate to the url again the data in the report has not refreshed.

If I manually click refresh on the report in PBI Service this updates the report visuals but only in PBI Service the web published report is still old data and it won't seem to refresh.
Update: it seems to refresh after an hour or so.

It doesn't seem to be a browser cache issue as I cleared everything there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web published reports update every 1 hour.
This seems to be independent of when the dataset refresh is.
Unfortunately I can no longer find the link to the documentation on this, feel free to add below.

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web#data-refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web#data-refresh)